# Nullable object must have a value. Linq FK

Tags: c#, linq

I am newish to linq and get this error everytime I do this join. One of the fields I'm joining on is nullable.

```
try
   {
    DCEDataContext dc = new DCEDataContext();
    List<Account> AcctWithChild=new List<Account>();
    AcctWithChild.Add(Account.GetById(3));
     //var query = (from acct in AcctWithChild
         List<CTRAC.WebApi.Models.Organization> Organizations = (from acct in AcctWithChild
                       join allOrg in dc.Organizations on acct.ID equals allOrg.AccountID
                       join allEngage in dc.Engagements on allOrg.in_id equals allEngage.OrganizationID
                       join allEngageForm in dc.EngagementForms on allEngage.ID equals allEngageForm.EngagementID
                       join allEnFormSub in dc.EngagementFormFilingSubmissions on allEngageForm.ID equals allEnFormSub.EngagementFormID
                       into EngagementFormFilingSubGroup
                       from allEnFormSub in EngagementFormFilingSubGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where allOrg.AccountID.HasValue
                       select new CTRAC.WebApi.Models.Organization { Name = allOrg.vc_BusinessName, OrganizationID = allOrg.OrganizationId,Return990_Id=allEngageForm.ID, EfileSubmissionDate=allEnFormSub.Timestamp }).Take(100).ToList();
```

*edit* When I make EfileSubmisionDate=null It goes through but setting it to allEnFormSub.Times which is sumtimes null gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

May be using `HasValue`

```
 List<CTRAC.WebApi.Models.Organization> Organizations = (from acct in AcctWithChild    
         join allOrg in dc.Organizations on acct.ID equals allOrg.AccountID??0
                       let MYID=allOrg.Field<Int?>("AccountID")
                       where MYID.HasValue
                       select new CTRAC.WebApi.Models.Organization { Name = allOrg.vc_BusinessName, OrganizationID = allOrg.OrganizationId,Return990_Id=5, EfileSubmissionDate=acct.TrialBegin.Value }).ToList();
```